# Is there a way in pandas to create an integer in a new column if a row contains a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the following dataframe:

[image: Initial DataFrame]

I want to transform the dataframe from above to something like this:

[image]

Thank's for any kind of help!

Comment: Please don't post images; the question should have self-contained code so that people can replicate what you're doing without having to re-type everything

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
df['Number'] = df.svn_changes.str.match(r'r\d+').cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is `contains` with regex and `cumsum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'svn_changes':['r123456','RowValueRow','ValueRowValue',
                                  'some_string_string','r234566','ValueRowValue',
                                  'some_string_string','r123789','something_here',
                                  'ValueRowValue','String_2','String_4']})

df['Number'] = df['svn_changes'].str.contains('r\d+').cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           svn_changes  Number
0              r123456       1
1          RowValueRow       1
2        ValueRowValue       1
3   some_string_string       1
4              r234566       2
5        ValueRowValue       2
6   some_string_string       2
7              r123789       3
8       something_here       3
9        ValueRowValue       3
10            String_2       3
11            String_4       3
```

Comment: Thanks!! Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple reusable line you can use to do that:

```py
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].str.contains('string_to_match')*1
```

The new column will have value `1` if the string is present in this column, and `0` otherwise.